# Why can't I access this value in an (OpenStruct) object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an (OpenStruct) object for which I can only seem to access some values. A simplified version of it is below:

```rb
#<Project::API::FormData::FormAnswer:0x007f94de911ed0 
    @form_answer=
        #<OpenStruct 
            user_id=130, 
            timer_value=[{"foo" => "bar"}]
        >
>
```

If I want to get `user_id`, that's easy

```
> answer.user_id
130
```

But what about timer_value?

```
> answer.timer_value
NoMethodError: undefined method `timer_value' for #<Project::API::FormData::FormAnswer:0x007f94de911ed0>
```

```
> answer.timer_value
NoMethodError: undefined method `timer_value' for #<Project::API::FormData::FormAnswer:0x007f94de911ed0>
```

maybe, for some reason, for this I need to access it through the form_answer first:

```
> answer.form_answer.timer_value
NoMethodError: undefined method `form_answer' for #<Project::API::FormData::FormAnswer:0x007f94de911ed0>
---
> answer.first.timer_value
NoMethodError: undefined method `first' for #<Project::API::FormData::FormAnswer:0x007f94de911ed0>
```

I'm not experienced with OpenStruct - is this the cause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an (OpenStruct) object

No, you don't. You seem to have a PORO<sup>*</sup> that has a field/instance_variable of type OpenStruct. And given the fact that `answer.user_id` works, you likely have something like this in that class:

```
delegate :user_id, to: :@form_answer
```

That is, `FormAnswer` class re-exports a property of one of its internal fields. But does not re-export `timer_value`, for example. Nor does it expose `@form_answer`.

---

<sup>* plain old ruby object</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sergio, I found that just as you posted - is indeed an issue in where the class is defined - which I thought that I'd read through, but as ever read and read again. It seems whomever created the class left a bug monkeying up the method definitions:

```
        fields.each do |field_name|
          define_method(field_name) { @form_answer.public_send(field_name) }
        end
```

Which is all good, but the `fields` array was malformed meaning only some values were coming through.

```
> answer.respond_to?(:timer_value)
true
```

Bingo!

Comment: I'd replace that loop with `delegate` or `def_delegators`.